# Download and install Python extension locally in IBM SPSS Modeler

Tags: python, spss-modeler

SPSS modeler Extension Transform - Python

Why I don't see Extension Transform ?

I want to use the Python program in SPSS Modeler, but I don't see the SPSS modeler Extension Transform - Python option.
I probably need to download and install the Python extension locally, but I can't find it.